# Why on live server I am getting this error?

Tags: php, database, yii, yii-extensions, rating

I am using dzraty extension for rating in my project made in Yii. It is working perfectly fine on local server. But on live server, I am getting this error:

> Alias "ext.DzRaty.DzRaty" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Make readable your extension file.

```
chmod 0444 path/to/your/file
```

Comment: Sorry what ? please explain

Comment: Maybe the extension file is not readable. You must make it readable.

Comment: If on live server everything the same as on local server, there is only one conclusion the extension file is not readable.
For changing file permission please read this article.
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm

Comment: I compare each and everything, everything is same. Ok let me see your article